# group indices of list in list of lists

Tags: python, list

I am looking for an elegant solution for the following problem.
I have a list of `ints` and I want to create a list of lists where the indices with the same value are grouped together in the order of the occurrences of said list.

`[2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2]` should yield `[[0, 5, 7], [1], [2, 3, 6], [4]]`
My solution so far:

```
list = [2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2]
cc = [[] for i in range(max(list)+1)]

for x in range(0, max(list)+1):
    cc[x] = []
    for i, j in enumerate(list):
        if j == x:
            cc[x].append(i)

print("cc: ", cc)
```

yields `[[1], [2, 3, 6], [0, 5, 7], [4]]`, which is obviously in the wrong order.

Comment: the output is right according to your code. cc[0] = [1] where 0 exists only at the index 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict()
lst = [2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2]
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    od.setdefault(x, []).append(i)
...
>>> od.values()
[[0, 5, 7], [1], [2, 3, 6], [4]]
```

Comment: I get `ValuesView(OrderedDict([(2, [0, 5, 7]), (0, [1]), (1, [2, 3, 6]), (3, [4])]))`. But how do I get this into an actual list in that exact order?

Comment: @sebastian In Python 3 call `list()` on it: `list(od.values())`