# make new python lists with indexes from items in a single list

Tags: python, list

I want to take a list, e.g. `[0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3]`, and make a list of lists of `(index + 1)` for each of the unique elements. For the above, for example, it would be `[[1, 3], [2, 4], [5, 6], [7]]`.

Right now my solution is the ultimate in clunkiness:

```
list_1 = [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3]
maximum = max(list_1)
master = []
for i in range(maximum + 1):
    temp_list = []
    for j,k in enumerate(list_1):
        if k == i:
            temp_list.append(j + 1)
    master.append(temp_list)
print master
```

Any thoughts on a more pythonic way to do this would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Maybe using an [orderedDict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978584/group-indices-of-list-in-list-of-lists) ?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're using 1-based indices in your output list. That could get confusing; OTOH https://xkcd.com/163 :)

Comment: Yeah, it's for output to another program that requires 1-based indices in their input :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this in two steps:

1. Build a map `{value: [list, of, indices], ...}`:

   ```
   index_map = {}
   for index, value in enumerate(list_1):
       index_map.setdefault(value, []).append(index+1)
   ```
2. Extract the value lists from the dictionary into your `master` list:

   ```
   master = [index_map.get(index, []) for index in range(max(index_map)+1)]
   ```

For your example, this would give:

```
>>> index_map
{0: [1, 3], 1: [2, 4], 2: [5, 6], 3: [7]}
>>> master
[[1, 3], [2, 4], [5, 6], [7]]
```

This implementation iterates over the whole list only once (`O(n)`, where `n` is `len(list_1)`) whereas the others so far iterate over the whole list once *for each unique element* (`O(n*m)`, where `m` is `len(set(list_1))`). By taking `max(d)` rather than `max(list_1)` you only need to iterate over the length of the unique items, which is also more efficient.

The implementation can be slightly simpler if you make [`d = collections.defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 0):

```
master = [[i+1 for i in range(len(list_1)) if list_1[i]==j] for j in range(max(list_1)+1)]
```

It is just the same that your current code, but it uses list comprehension which is often a quite good pythonic way to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Note that this is `O(len(list_1)*len(set(list_1)))`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Interesting, however OP did not talk about efficiency but simplicity (which is your solution more than mine anyway).

Answer (score 0):

```
list_1 = [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3]
master = []
for i in range(max(list_1)+1):
    master.append([j+1 for j,k in enumerate(list_1) if k==i])
```

Comment: Note that this is `O(len(list_1)*len(set(list_1)))`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Noted. However, the question regarded making the code more "Pythonic", not more efficient. I would argue that OP's code was not immediately readable ("readability counts"), and that was the problem. Your solution is good not because of efficiency, but because it is both readable *and* efficient.